# Hidden sheets API Js office

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, typescript, office365

I need your help in order to create one or more sheets hidden with data in API JS for Office.
Thanks for your help I'm concern with this topic, I not found examples about it.

Comment: examples please

Comment: hey, welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the how to ask a good question guide. It will help you get answers. :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tony, thank you so much for your suggestions.

Comment: Tony, Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Tony. I have two sheets, in sheet1 need show data, In the sheet2  want insert other data and hide this sheet. the information is inserted in the sheet2 success, but don't accomplished hide it. I am using coercionType.table to insert data in the sheet2. Code lines. let workSheet = this.ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(Sheet2);
        workSheet.load("visibility");
        workSheet.visibility = Excel.SheetVisibility.veryHidden;        
        this.workSheetName = "Sheet1";
        let Sheet1 = this.ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(this.workSheetName);
        Sheet1.activate();

Comment: Can anyone help me with this topic, I'm desperate with the subject. Thanks